# High res image, but small file < 2.0MB?

Tags: jquery, html, css, png, jpeg

Can someone with experience in website design/development, explain the method Google, Microsoft, and other website are using to make these high res photos backgrounds in their webpages while keeping the file size very small.

here are some examples:

https://plus.google.com/+Gmail/posts

http://www.xbox.com/en-US/#fbid=FrRSDRhcxBm

Comment: Check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UNWi7FA36M

Comment: Neither of those examples work for me. Google plus has no photo background, but a plain grey one, and the Xbox page has no background photo, but a large video (which is about 20 MB in size).

Comment: Throw it through Photoshop and save as for Web & Devices it will do it for you.

Comment: This should not be on hold as these tools are directly used for fronted development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some free online services you can use, for png and jpeg respectively:

- https://tinypng.com
- http://jpeg-optimizer.com

In addition, Google also promotes the use of the .webp format which creates smaller field, although it isn't fully supported across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if were' talking about the same images as these pages are personalized and change often, but [this Google's image](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-mwSmR54SmWo/UyIu9OuIXtI/AAAAAAAAd7Y/H_wiiEu_-14/w1000-h562-no/Google%252B_Gmail.png) is a 200KB PNG which can be compressed down to 72KB with [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com)/[pngquant](http://pngquant.org).

For JPEGs check out [JPEGMini](http://jpegmini.com).